# Django-Memsql Initial Migration Error

Tags: mysql, django, django-orm, singlestore, django-contenttypes

I am getting the following error on my initial migration with django 1.10 with mysql backend connected to a 3 node MemSQL cluster.

django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1895, "The unique key named: 'django_content_type_app_label_76bd3d3b_uniq' must contain al
l columns specified in the primary key when no shard key is declared")

I believe that this is the issue:
[MemSQL - Surrogate key as Primary and different unique keys at the same time in table creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40520136/memsql-surrogate-key-as-primary-and-different-unique-keys-at-the-same-time-in)

Any workaround/solution will be much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: This is a good question because the problem is not with user code, but with built-in Django models and the resultant SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your running into the same issue you linked to. MemSQL has limited support for unique keys that aren't the shard key (they are expensive for a distributed database to maintain).

Outside of changing django to make the table with the unique keys a REFERENCE table I don't think there is a good work around.

Comment: Yes makes sense given MemSQL's distributed design. Thanks Adam